# FFForm jquery not clearing form on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Pulling my hair out on this one.

I'm using jquery.ffform.js with my website and have created a form using the code below:

```
<div id="contactus" style="display:none">

 <section id="getintouch" class="fadeIn animated">
    <div class="container" style="border-bottom: 0;">
        <h1>
            <span>SEND US YOUR QUERY NOW</span>
        </h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="contact" action="#" method="post" id="form" onload="">
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="lbl">
                <label for="name">
                    Name</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ctrl">
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name" data-required="true" data-validation="text"
                    data-msg="Invalid Name" placeholder="Ex: John Donga" 
                    onfocus="if(this.value === 'value') { this.value = ''; }" value=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="lbl">
                <label for="email">
                    E-Mail</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ctrl">
                <input type="text" id="email" name="email" data-required="true" data-validation="email"
                    data-msg="Invalid E-Mail" placeholder="Ex: youremail@domain.com">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="lbl">
                <label for="email">
                    Phone</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ctrl">
                <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" data-required="true" data-validation="custom"
                    data-msg="Invalid Phone #" placeholder="Ex: 111-258-444">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="lbl">
                <label for="subject">
                    Subject</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ctrl">
                <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Ex: Quote for Project">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row clearfix">
            <div class="lbl">
                <label for="message">
                    Message</label>
            </div>
            <div class="ctrl">
                <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="6" cols="10"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row  clearfix">
            <div class="span10 offset2">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit" value="Send Message">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        <div id="success">
            Your E-Mail has been sent successfully!</div>
        <div id="error">
            Unable to send e-mail at the moment, please try later.</div>
        <div id="validation">
        </div>


    </div>

</section>
```

What I want it to do is allow the user to key in his or her contact details and submit the query.  This works like a charm, it calls the email.php script and sends an e-mail to the correct mail address.  It's right at the end, when it says "Mail successfully sent", I click the OK button and it goes back to the form without clearing it down.  I've checked through the ffform code and it doesn't allude to clearing the form after entry.  The official website, [egrappler](http://www.egrappler.com/ffform-free-jquery-contact-form-plugin-with-validations-amazing-css3-animation/), provides a downloadable demo but even that doesn't clear the form.

Anyone got any ideas?

By the way, the javascript at the start of the page is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getScript('js/jquery.ffform.js', function(){
        $('#form').ffform({ animation: 'fade', 
                            submitButton: '#submit', 
                            validationIndicator: '#validation', 
                            errorIndicator: '#error', 
                            successIndicator: '#success', 

                            'fields': [{ 'id': 'name', required: true, requiredMsg: 'Name is required', type: 'alpha', validate: true, msg: 'Invalid Name' },
                                       { 'id': 'email', required: true, requiredMsg: 'E-Mail is required', type: 'email', validate: true, msg: 'Invalid E-Mail Address' }, 
                                       { 'id': 'phone', required: false, type: 'custom', validate: false, msg: 'Invalid Phone #' }, 
                                       { 'id': 'message', required: true, requiredMsg: 'Cat got your tongue?', type: 'text', validate: false, msg: ''}] });
    });
});

</script>
```

Hope someone can help.

Many thanks!

Dave

Comment: `$('#form')[0].reset();` would reset the FORM

Comment: Hi, I added it to the end of the script in my html file and it didn't work.  Would it be easier to just get the page to reload at the end of the script, rather than clearing the form (as reloading the page hides my email form)?

Comment: You have to add it once the request is done, in success callback. Now if you prefer to reload all the page, then just do it